# Amazon EC2 Socket Programming (C)

Tags: c, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm basically trying to read accelerometer data on Raspberry Pi (my client) and send them over to the server (EC2 ubuntu instance).

This is my client code:

```
#include "./sensor.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 4) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    int delay = atoi(argv[3]);
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    int acc[6];
    enableIMU();
    while(1){
    bzero(buffer,256);
    readACC(acc);
    sprintf(buffer,"%d\t%d\t%d\t\n", acc[0], acc[1], acc[2]);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

I put this in command line on my client and see my accelerometer readings:

```
./client ec2-54-187-93-10.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 8000
```

I then put this line on my server and see nothing:

```
./server 8000
```

This is the security group of my instance:

```
Type            Protocol          Port Range               Source
HTTP              TCP                 80                  0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule   TCP                8000                 0.0.0.0/0
SSH               TCP                 22                  0.0.0.0/0
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger or add some more basic debug statements to your code to help you trace the execution. For example, you don't even have a debug print for when the server has successfully accepted a connection.

Comment: With server and client local to each other, it appears to work fine.  It's most likely a firewall issue on one side or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips to find the problem.
You can use this to find whether your server started or no.

```
fuser 8000/tcp
```

If it is fine, you can use telnet:

```
telnet localhost:8000
```

And try to send something to your server, in your case this should happen:

```
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
```

If you can see that port is busy, but you can't see received message sent via telnet, then you should more debug to client and identify problem.

Comment: These are good suggestions on how to debug the problem further. But it isn't really an answer and should be posted as a comment.